# how to insert a single line in the end of multiple .txt files in a single folder using batch or vbs?

Tags: batch-file, text, vbscript, insert, lines

i have multiple text files on notepad placed in a directory i.e d:\documents.I want a batch file to add a line at the end of each of them but they are more than 60 or 70 of them.Just need a batch file to add this line automatically.Any ideas please???

Answer (score 1):

You might have to worry about files that are missing the newline character at the end of the last line. If you simply append a new line, it will be appended to the last line instead of adding a new line.

The following should work with any file, regardless whether the last line ends with a newline character. It conditionally appends a newline character before appending the new line if and only if the original file last line is missing the terminating newline character.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set LF=^


:: The above two blank lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

for %%F in (d:\documents\*.txt) do (
  findstr /v "!LF!" "%%F" >nul && (echo()
  (echo Your new line goes here)
)>>"%%F"
```

The above will not work if any file names contain `!`. In the unlikely event that you do have file names that contain `!`, then you will need to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set LF=^


:: The above two blank lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

for %%F in (d:\documents\*.txt) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  findstr /v "!LF!" "!file!" >nul && (echo()
  endlocal
  (echo Your new line goes here)
)>>"%%F"
```

---

**UPDATE**

As foxidrive pointed out in his comment, the above solutions will append Windows style lines ending with `<CR><LF>` to Unix style files with lines ending with `<LF>`. Such hybrid line types may not be desireable.

The code below will properly append the line with the correct line terminator. The code assumes any file that contains a `<CR>` is in Windows format. It also assumes any file that does not contain `<LF>` is in Windows format.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "line=YOUR NEW LINE GOES HERE"

:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set LF=^


:: The above two blank lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

for %%F in (d:\test\test\*.txt) do (
  set "unix="
  findstr $ "%%F" >nul || cmd /v:on /c "findstr "!LF!" "%%F" >nul" && set unix=1
  cmd /v:on /c findstr /v "!LF!" "%%F" ^>nul && (
    if defined unix (cmd /v:on /c "echo(&echo(!lf!"|findstr /v $) else (echo()
  )
  if defined unix (
    cmd /v:on /c "echo(&echo(!line!!lf!"|findstr /v $
  ) else (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
  )
)>>"%%F"
```

Comment: There's a nifty use of `findstr` Dave - see my answer.

Comment: @foxidrive - Close, but that technique is not reliable. See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Dave, your code doesn't work reliably with Unix files either.  It appends CRLF sets and so creates hybrid files.

Comment: @foxidrive - True, a unix style file could become hybrid as you say. But it would have the correct number of lines. The hybrid nature may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @foxidrive - I've added a solution that does not create hybrid files.

Comment: That's above and beyond the call of duty, Dave. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off

>"%TEMP%\newline.txt" echo.

pushd "C:\documents"
for %%f in (*.txt) do copy /b "%%~f" + "%TEMP%\newline.txt" "%%~f"
popd

del "%TEMP%\temp.txt"
```

- `>"%TEMP%\temp.txt" echo.`: create a (temporary) file with just a newline in it.
- `pushd "C:\documents"`: change the current working directory to `C:\documents`.
- `for %%f in (*.txt) do ...`: iterate over all text files in the current directory.
- `copy /b "%%~f" + "%TEMP%\newline.txt" "%%~f"`: copy the content of the current file plus the newline from the temporary file back to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

This code will add a CRLF to the end of every file if it does not have one,
and will then add the text `This is the last line` as the last line of each file.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /a:-d /b') do (
   findstr /v ".*$" "%%a" >nul && (>>"%%a" echo.)
   >>"%%a" echo This is the last line
)
```

Comment: Using FINDSTR /V ".*$" to detect files with missing newline on last line will only work properly for Windows based files that have `<CR><LF>` at the end of each line. Unix style files that end with `<LF>` will mistakenly get the extra line because the `$` anchor simply looks for a `<CR>` character. It is not uncommon to find Unix style files on a Windows machine.

Comment: @dbenham Yes Dave that's true, it won't handle Unix formatted files the same way.  It does however work well on Windows files and doesn't need delayed expansion.